# get all td in XPath c#

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse HTML using HtmlAgilityPack in C#. I have `21 tr items` and each tr items have `7 td items`. How can I get all tr and td items in order? Now I can get only one tr item and its 7 td items.

Here is my C# Code:

```
var url = "url";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(sourceCode);


            var name = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[1]")[0].InnerText;
            var year = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]")[0].InnerText;
            var km = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]")[0].InnerText;
            var color = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]")[0].InnerText;
           var price = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]")[0].InnerText;
            var date = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]")[0].InnerText;
            var location = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]")[0].InnerText;
```

I tried to use `[@id=\"searchResultsTable\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[position()<8]` but is returns only /n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code (not tested. Chances of compile errors. But gives you an Idea.)

Comments in the code gives you more details.

```
//GET THE TABLE NODE
HtmlNode table = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='searchResultsTable']");

//LOOP THROUGH THE TABLE NODE AND FIND EACH TR 
foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//tr")) {

      //PRINT HERE WHATEVER YOU WANT FOR EACH ROW.
      Console.WriteLine("New Row");

      //LOOP THROUGH THE ALL TD OF EACH TR
      foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("//td")) {
          //PRINT HERE EACH TD
          Console.WriteLine("cell: " + cell.InnerText);
      } //END TD

}//END TR
```

Comment: I have tested your code. Instead of "td" and "tr", it is "//td" and "//tr". Otherwise it gets stuck in the tbody and can't find them. With that change it works fine.

Comment: Thank you! the solution works fine! Is there any way to not get div's under tr/td. `//*[@id="searchResultsTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]` I do not want to get these divs. I just want to get tds. @katamarayudu @derloopkat

Comment: @heyaa *cell.ChildNodes.First().InnerText* will get you the text at root level of td and ignore the content of nested tags. For example *<td>Year 1<div>XXX</div></td>* returns *Year 1*. However you need to check td is not empty at all *if(cell.ChildNodes.Count > 0) { //get text here    }*

Comment: How can I exclude some tr's? In my HTML, in row tr[5] , there is nothing. Therefore, NullReferenceException occurred. I tried  `//tr(* except tr[5])`. @derloopkat

Comment: @heyaa, Same way I've mentioned for td you can do for tr, add an *IF* statement to check whether there are child nodes. Another option it's just check for inner text empty for the tr. In order to ignore spaces use Trim().

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what's been mentioned, query with a selector to loop on `tr` elements then select your fixed position `td` nodes per row:

**Assuming a structure like the following:**

```
<table id="searchResultsTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Name<a>Name 1</a></td>
    <td>Year 1</td>
    <td>KM 1</td>
    <td>Color 1</td>
    <td>Price 1</td>
    <td>Date 1</td>
    <td>Location 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Name<a>Name 2</a></td>
    <td>Year 2</td>
    <td>KM 2</td>
    <td>Color 2</td>
    <td>Price 2</td>
    <td>Date 2</td>
    <td>Location 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**Example:**

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.Load("example.html");

var rows = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='searchResultsTable']/tbody/tr");

foreach(var row in rows)
{
    var name = row.SelectSingleNode("td[2]/a[1]").InnerText;
    var year = row.SelectSingleNode("td[3]").InnerText;
    var km = row.SelectSingleNode("td[4]").InnerText;
    var color = row.SelectSingleNode("td[5]").InnerText;
    var price = row.SelectSingleNode("td[6]").InnerText;
    var date = row.SelectSingleNode("td[7]").InnerText;
    var location = row.SelectSingleNode("td[8]").InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}", name, year, km, color, price, date, location);
}
```

**Produces:**

```
Name 1, Year 1, KM 1, Color 1, Price 1, Date 1, Location 1
Name 2, Year 2, KM 2, Color 2, Price 2, Date 2, Location 2
```

Comment: I tried your solution. I do not know why but I get only 3 tr's. @JohnL

Comment: I understand why I get only 3 trs. Because tr[4] is empty.